# SQL Server change a Self-Join to a CTE with ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a nice self-join query based on a left join on ranges. in the last period the preformance of the query started to degrade and i'm trying to optimize this query by migrating it to a CTE or any other solution will be nice.

```
select distinct Main.Id, Main.Name, Main.PolicyRef, Main.ExtCategoryId, Main.NodeLevel, Main.Description
from tbl1 as Main left join
     tbl1 as Cat
     on (Cat.LeftN between Main.LeftN and Main.RightN and Cat.RightN between Main.LeftN and Main.RightN
       OR
        Cat.LeftN between Main.RightN and Main.LeftN and Cat.RightN between Main.RightN and Main.LeftN
      ) and cat.Id=main.Id
where Cat.Id in (select CategoryRef from tbl2 where AccountRef=@AccountRef and ItemRef=@MId)


 set statistics io on
```

Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table 'tbl1'. Scan count 1, logical reads 19903, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table 'tbl2'. Scan count 1, logical reads 123, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i need help to migrate this to a recursive CTE. all my attempts up to now failed in producing a more performant CTE.

Comment: Why do you think you need a recursive cte? Instead of deciding how to query this maybe you need to explain what you want. Start with table definitions and sample data along with the desired output for the sample data. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a great place to start.

Comment: Classic XY question.  You WANT to optimize your query, and you think migrating it to a CTE might do it, so you ask how to do that.   It's more likely that there's a better way to optimize your query, but we don't have nearly enough detail to help right now.